# nuxt 3 navigateTo with target blank not working

Tags: javascript, navigation, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I have installed version Nuxt `3.0.0` and used the navigateTo method to redirect users to 3rd party website. I want to use the open 3rd party website in a new window.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
await navigateTo('https://nuxt.com', {  
  open: {
    target: '_blank',
  }
})
</script>
```

I have tried the above code according to mentioned in Nuxt 3 official document but it is not redirecting to the new window.

Comment: "not working" isn't a good technical description of a problem.  explain the actual behavior.

Comment: using Nuxt example app [in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-examples-vqzyc1?file=app.vue) it works ok.  do you have pop-up blocker active?

Comment: @yoduh https://i.imgur.com/HUzXW8c.png Please check this I have allowed all popup windows in Chrome and firefox as well but it returns the same behaviour and redirecting to the same window instead of a new

Answer (score 0):

```js
await navigateTo('https://nuxt.com', {  
  open: {
    target: '_blank',
  },
  external: true
});
```

[Navigating to an external URL is not allowed by default](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/navigate-to#external-url)